# two backward transitions with data-rel='back in android phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing application in android using phonegap.

On every page I have used `<a href="" data-rel="back">Back</a>`
but on click it takes me back to first page of application.
Even if i click on close button of modal-popup, it takes me to first page of application.
for close of modal-popup i have defined as

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
```

Please help me in this, to avoid this backward transitions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should it be `href="#"` instead of just `href=""`?

Comment: add `data-history="false"` to popup div.